# Zend Framework get dependent rows following a certain condition

Tags: zend-framework, one-to-many, conditional-statements, zend-db-table, table-relationships

I want to retrieve rows from a dependent table that follows a given criteria in the dependent table.

Comment: I wanted to help so i would give you this http://www.zendcasts.com/category/screencasts/databases/zend-db/  , but you didn't provide any helpful info ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using table relationships, you can provide a `Zend_Db_Table_Select` object as an argument to `findDependentRowset`

```
$row->findDependentRowset($table, $rule, $select);
```

See more info at http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.relationships.html#zend.db.table.relationships.fetching.dependent

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a join http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html#zend.db.select.building.join

But with no more info that's all I can give